# data-parsley-mincheck checks all checkboxes by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, parsley.js

I have Rails 4 and Parsley-Rails installed.

My form has multiple checkboxes,user needs to check at least 3 to save form in database..

But my code don't work. It checks all checkboxes by default.

My form:

```
<%= form_for(@advertisement, :html => {"data-parsley-validate" => true,:multipart => true},remote: true, format: :json) do |f| %>

 <% @services.each do |service| %>
                  <li>
                     <%= check_box_tag 'service_ids[]', service.id ,:html =>{:'data-parsley-mincheck'=>3}%>
                      <%= h service.id %>


                  </li>
           <% end %>

<%end%>
```

Generated HTML looks like this:

```
  <input checked="checked" id="service_ids_" name="service_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="2" data-parsley-multiple="service_ids" data-parsley-id="7696">

    <input checked="checked" id="service_ids_" name="service_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="3" data-parsley-multiple="service_ids" data-parsley-id="7696">
```

I have tried many other ways to set mincheck:

```
  <%= check_box_tag 'service_ids[]', service.id ,:'data-parsley-mincheck'=>3%>
```

but still can't find working solution..

Any ideas ?
Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by "It checks all checkboxes by default"??

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune when I reload page all checkboxes are already checked .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [doc of `check_box_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag). Options are the 4th argument, not the third.

Comment: ` <%= check_box_tag 'service_ids[]', service.id ,:checked => false,:html =>{:'data-parsley-mincheck'=>'3'}%> ` Still the same problem ...

Comment: Still same problem, as you still didn't count to 4.